# Django 1.5 override abstractuser email field to be required and unique

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a custom user model extending AbstractUser. I have added two custom fields. But i want the default email field to be uniqe and required . I have searched a lot on the net, but could not find a good advice.

Is it the right way to do that in extended usercreationform  with overridden 'clean_email' method?

Thanx

Answer (score 9):

Im facing the same problem, I'm extending the AbstractUser as I only need to add info. This was the only thing that worked for me:

```
AbstractUser._meta.get_field('email')._unique = True
```

That solves the unique problem, but still I can't make it required, when you extend AbstractUser it email field IS NOT, it can be noticed if you add a extended user from the admin and also because the forms dont take it that way.

I've tried

```
AbstractUser._meta.get_field('email')._blank = False
AbstractUser._meta.get_field('email')._null = False
```

But it doesn't seem to work.

EDIT:
For some reason unique works with '_', but blank and null don't, I just tried this

```
AbstractUser._meta.get_field('email').blank = False
AbstractUser._meta.get_field('email').null = False
```

And it worked!

Comment: This works in 1.6 but App registry changed with 1.7. Any idea on how to adapt this answer for use in 1.7? As-is you are raised ``raise AppRegistryNotReady("Models aren't loaded yet.")``

Comment: Sorry Flowpoke, I haven't moved to 1.7 yet so I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: One solution is to use the AppConfig system itself and call `AbstractUser._meta.get_field('email')._unique = True` in side and AppConfig's ready method. More details below, it seems to be working for me.

Answer (score 3):

`email` is already in the `AbstractUser.REQUIRED_FIELDS`.

To make it unique:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    ...

(emailField,) = (f for f in User._meta.fields if f.name == "email")
emailField.unique = True
```

Kinda hacky but should work

Or you could simple extend the `AbstractBaseUser` and add the missing stuff from the `AbstractUser` yourself with your custom tweaks

Comment: If you run this in the main body of the class `User` is undefined (as is `self`). I tried it in `__init__` and get `AttributeError: can't set attribute`.

Comment: I wouldn't run this in the `__init__` or anywhere inside the class definition. Just put this right **under** the class definition

Comment: In Django 1.7, it doesn't work. I have found this solution working: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26108834/865664

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could override the `__init__` on your model to make the field required and unique.

UPDATE

After a little playing around I've found this easier said than done (I haven't found a way of making a field in a child class required whilst `required = False` on the parent).

Comment: I have already created the model and added some users so i can not override it from extended abstractuser model. It gives -- FieldError: Local field 'email' in class 'CustomUser' clashes with field of similar name from base class 'AbstractUser' --

Comment: I could not find a solution for the question. I think it will be best to extend 'AbstractBaseUser'.  ???

Answer (score 0):

mderk's answer did not exactly work for me - I got `AttributeError: can't set attribute`. The reason being that internally Django saves `unique`'s value in `self._unique`.

So to make a long story short:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    ...

(emailField,) = (f for f in User._meta.fields if f.name == "email")
emailField._unique = True
```

works.

**Or even better**:

```
User._meta.get_field('email')._unique = True
```

Answer (score 0):

The somewhat hacky though effective solution given here doesn't work in Django 1.7

```
User._meta.get_field('email')._unique = True
```

This is because accessing a model in module scope violates the AppRegistry assertion that models shouldn't be modified until loading is complete:

```
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Models aren't loaded yet.
```

You can use the new [App Loading](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/applications/) feature to do this for you. Define a AppConfig class with a `ready` method which does the monkey patch in `apps.py` in your app directory.

```
from django.apps import AppConfig

class YourAppConfig(AppConfig):
    name="your_app_name"

    def ready(self):
        from .models import MyAbstractUser
        MyAbstractUser._meta.get_field_by_name('email')[0]._unique=True
```

This assume that `MyAbstractUser` is a subclass of `AbstractUser`.

You will also have to modify `__init__.py` in your app's directory:

```
default_app_config = 'your_app_name.apps.YourAppConfig'
```

If you forget your new `ready` method won't be called.

Now your system checks should pass.

Answer (score 0):

```
AbstractUser._meta.get_field('email')._unique = True
AbstractUser._meta.get_field('email').blank = False
AbstractUser._meta.get_field('email').null = False
```

It worked and I checked the database. However, when I create a user from the default admin page it will create it without problems and with the email field empty. It will only ask for the email when you try to save it.
But it still being a goog solution.
I didn't even need sudo.
I recommend making sure that you require the email when creating a new user from the views.
*Using django 1.10 and SQlite3

This will also give you an idea of the fields you can override:

(If someone finds a way to making a field required when you create it please leave a comment :) )

```
dir(User._meta.get_field('email'))
Out[3]: 
['__class__',
 '__copy__',
 '__deepcopy__',
 '__delattr__',
 '__dict__',
 '__doc__',
 '__eq__',
 '__format__',
 '__ge__',
 '__getattribute__',
 '__gt__',
 '__hash__',
 '__init__',
 '__le__',
 '__lt__',
 '__module__',
 '__new__',
 '__reduce__',
 '__reduce_ex__',
 '__repr__',
 '__setattr__',
 '__sizeof__',
 '__str__',
 '__subclasshook__',
 '__unicode__',
 '__weakref__',
 '_blank',
 '_check_backend_specific_checks',
 '_check_choices',
 '_check_db_index',
 '_check_deprecation_details',
 '_check_field_name',
 '_check_max_length_attribute',
 '_check_null_allowed_for_primary_keys',
 '_description',
 '_error_messages',
 '_get_flatchoices',
 '_get_lookup',
 '_get_val_from_obj',
 '_unique',
 '_unregister_lookup',
 '_validators',
 '_verbose_name',
 'attname',
 'auto_created',
 'auto_creation_counter',
 'blank',
 'cached_col',
 'check',
 'choices',
 'class_lookups',
 'clean',
 'clone',
 'column',
 'concrete',
 'contribute_to_class',
 'creation_counter',
 'db_check',
 'db_column',
 'db_index',
 'db_parameters',
 'db_tablespace',
 'db_type',
 'db_type_suffix',
 'deconstruct',
 'default',
 'default_error_messages',
 'default_validators',
 'description',
 'editable',
 'empty_strings_allowed',
 'empty_values',
 'error_messages',
 'flatchoices',
 'formfield',
 'get_attname',
 'get_attname_column',
 'get_cache_name',
 'get_choices',
 'get_col',
 'get_db_converters',
 'get_db_prep_save',
 'get_db_prep_value',
 'get_default',
 'get_filter_kwargs_for_object',
 'get_internal_type',
 'get_lookup',
 'get_pk_value_on_save',
 'get_prep_value',
 'get_transform',
 'has_default',
 'help_text',
 'hidden',
 'is_relation',
 'many_to_many',
 'many_to_one',
 'max_length',
 'model',
 'name',
 'null',
 'one_to_many',
 'one_to_one',
 'pre_save',
 'primary_key',
 'register_lookup',
 'rel',
 'rel_db_type',
 'related_model',
 'remote_field',
 'run_validators',
 'save_form_data',
 'select_format',
 'serialize',
 'set_attributes_from_name',
 'system_check_deprecated_details',
 'system_check_removed_details',
 'to_python',
 'unique',
 'unique_for_date',
 'unique_for_month',
 'unique_for_year',
 'validate',
 'validators',
 'value_from_object',
 'value_to_string',
 'verbose_name']
```