# Django 1.7 - Modifying a model's property

Tags: django, django-1.7

Previously in Django 1.6 and earlier versions, I used to do the following to make `User`'s email attribute unique:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username']

User._meta.get_field_by_name('email')[0]._unique=True
```

I'm migrating to Django 1.7 but this code is raising the following error:

```
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Models aren't loaded yet.
```

traced all the way back to `User._meta.get_field_by_name('email')[0]._unique=True`.

How should I migrate this to Django 1.7?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/applications/), `ready()` method of `AppConfig` is called when the registry is populated which means models are also loaded, therefore referencing models shouldn't be a problem.

That line of code is still not valid as it is in `ready()` though, as pointed out in the documentation:

> You cannot import models in modules that define application
>   configuration classes, but you can use get_model() to access a model
>   class by name

Therefore, remove `User._meta.get_field_by_name('email')[0]._unique=True` from `models.py` and do the following in your app configuration instead:

```
class AccountsConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'modules.accounts'

    def ready(self):
        self.get_model('User')._meta.get_field_by_name('email')[0]._unique=True
```